# Google Watch This Space, Social Icons

Tags: jquery, social-networking, share

Google has a cool feature on their [Watch This Space](http://www.google.com/adwords/watchthisspace/) page.  On the right side, it shows icons and when you hover over it, it expands and changes color.

Would anyone have any idea how to do this in jQuery? I've tried a few things, but nothing even close or worth posting.  Any help or point in the right direction would be awesome.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use animate:

```
$('#someID').animate({
    width: '100px',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2u9E5/

It uses jQueryUI as well

---

Here is a fiddle that utilizes different colors: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2u9E5/6/